# Consuming JSON array in PENTAHO as JSON input

Tags: json, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have the following JSON structure. There are two arrays fields and data. The fields are in the fields array and the data is in the data array. I want to be able to use the fields as the data fields.

{"fields":["cik","name","ticker","exchange"],"data":[[320193,"Apple Inc.","AAPL","Nasdaq"],[789019,"MICROSOFT CORP","MSFT","Nasdaq"],[1318605,"Tesla, Inc.","TSLA","Nasdaq"],[1067983,"BERKSHIRE HATHAWAY INC","BRK-B","NYSE"],[731766,"UNITEDHEALTH GROUP INC","UNH","NYSE"]]}

I want to be able to output the data as:

| CIK | NAME | TICKER | EXCHANGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 320193 | Apple Inc. | AAPL | NASDAQ |
| 789019 | MICROSOFT CORP | MSFT | NASDAQ |

I have tried $..field and $..data i get 0ne row. And when splitting data to rows does not map to fields.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, you can use https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/# to get an idea.

However, sometimes having success on the site, you may not be able to on pentaho.

But the most I got was the path below, see if it helps.

```
cik -> $[*].[*].[0]
name -> $[*].[*].[1]
ticker -> $[*].[*].[2]
exchange -> $[*].[*].[3]
```

Obs.: Sorry for my english, using google translator

img pentaho:
[image: img pentaho]